# Bullet and numbered list in not rendering with bullets and numbers

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, bulletedlist

I am binding a decoded html consisting of list and text. But its failing to render bullets/numbers in case of `OL LI/UL LI`

Markup:

```
@HTML.Raw(httputlity.htmldecode(model.defn))
```

definition value after decoding will be

```
<ol><li>test</li><li>test2</li></ol>Sample text
```

Displayed as

```
test
test2
Sample Text
```

Must be displayed as

```
1. test
2. test2
Sample Text
test2
```

Answer (score 1):

the 1, 2 and the bullets are rendered by the browser parsing the `<ul>` and `<ol>` tags. They're not part of the HTML

Not too sure I understand your question though.

Answer (score 1):

It is simple, you have to write a CSS class for that OL tag

```
ol.yourOLCLASS
{
  list-style-type:number;
}
```